# How to change the below target in run time in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

For example, I have a imageView 1 , imageView 2 and imageView3

In the XML I use a relative layout to group them

```
eg.
imageView1:
below of 2

imageView3:
visiblity: gone
```

after certain action (in run time)

```
eg.
imageView1:
below of 3

imageView3:
visiblity: visible
```

I think something similiar, but can not find the correct syntax

```
imageView1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(Below));
```

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's your API level? If, by chance, you are using a min SDK of 17, you can just use [removeRule(int verb)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#removeRule%28int%29) to remove the `below of 2` and then add `below of 3`.

Otherwise, what I do is I keep two instances of RelativeLayout.LayoutParams for a given view. Try something like this:

`belowTwoParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, 2.getId());
belowThreeParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, 3.getId());`

Where belowTwoParams and belowThreeParams are both instances of RelativeLayout.LayoutParams. Keep in mind that your "2" and "3" views need to have valid IDs, set either in the XML or programatically before adding these rules.
Afterwards, you just call `imageView1.setLayoutParams(belowTwoParams //or belowThreeParams accordingly);`